# NLTK - Access Brown corpus as one file

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus, linguistics

I have recently started working with NLTK, and I have downloaded the Brown corpus to do analyze its data. However, I see that the corpus is split into around 500 files.

I need to run a script on the content of the whole corpus, though. Is there a way to access the content of the whole corpus, or do I need to for loop through the content of each file and append it to a new file?

Thank you!

Comment: pls refer [read the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list), and let us know if you still need any help. if so, pls show your code and can advise where it needs a fix.

Comment: if they didn't create function to load all files then you have to do it on your own.